# Angular ng-messages: how to check password confirmation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, ionic-framework, ng-messages

**THE SITUATION:**

I am using [ng-messages](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) directive for instant validation in my angular app. Everything is working fine except one thing: i need to validate the field 'password confirmation' and don't know how to do.

**THE CODE:**

```
<form name="autentication_form" novalidate="" ng-submit="submit_register()">

    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Email</span>
        <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="registerData.email" required>

        <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="autentication_form.email.$error" role="alert" ng-if='autentication_form.email.$dirty'>
            <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">You did not enter the email</div>
        </div>
    </label>

    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Password</span>
        <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="registerData.password" required>

        <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="autentication_form.password.$error" role="alert" ng-if='autentication_form.password.$dirty'>
            <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">Please enter the password</div>
        </div>
    </label>

    <label class="item item-input">
        <span class="input-label">Password confirmation</span>
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="registerData.password_confirmation" required>

        <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="autentication_form.password_confirmation.$error" role="alert" ng-if='autentication_form.password_confirmation.$dirty'>
            <div class="form-error" ng-message="required">Password confirmation required</div>
        </div>
    </label>

</form>
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i check that the password confirmation match using ng-messages?

Answer (score 22):

The easiest approach is to use a pattern. Works fine for me!

```
<input type="password" name="new_password1" ng-model="new_password1">

<input type="password" name="new_password2" ng-pattern="\b{{new_password1}}\b" ng-model="new_password2">
<div ng-messages="passwordForm.new_password2.$error">
    <div ng-message="pattern">Not equal!!!</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like the best and easiest solution. I'd change the pattern a little bit to match the full line though: `ng-pattern="^{{new_password1}}$"`

Comment: This is awesome. How would I avoid the Parse Lexer error though? I get "Unexpected next character"

Comment: @Jared to fix the Parse Lexer error the pattern should be wrapped with /:

`ng-pattern="/^{{new_password1}}$/"`

Comment: Just read the API reference from the angular page
[link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)

_If the expression evaluates to a string, then it will be converted to a RegExp after wrapping it in ^ and $ characters. For instance, "abc" will be converted to new RegExp('^abc$')._

**That means you can use ng-pattern="{{new_password1}}**

Comment: @ebastuart What happens when the password contains characters that have meaning in the regexp (like * and +)?

Comment: @ebastuart you're right I just tested it and if password contains regexp then the ng-pattern will fail and not match. So doesn't look like using ng-pattern is a workable solution.

Comment: DON'T USE THIS, this answer is failing if the password contains regular expression valid characters like /, $, etc.

Comment: Great solution, @ebastuart!

Answer (score 10):

The best approach is to use a directive. The major point of problem here is that both password and password confirmation inputs need to be watched.

Here's the solution that could help

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngMessages'])

.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.registerData = {};
})


.directive('confirmPwd', function($interpolate, $parse) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ngModelCtrl) {

      var pwdToMatch = $parse(attr.confirmPwd);
      var pwdFn = $interpolate(attr.confirmPwd)(scope);

      scope.$watch(pwdFn, function(newVal) {
          ngModelCtrl.$setValidity('password', ngModelCtrl.$viewValue == newVal);
      })

      ngModelCtrl.$validators.password = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        var value = modelValue || viewValue;
        return value == pwdToMatch(scope);
      };

    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@~1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular-messages@1.4.3" data-semver="1.4.3" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular-messages.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="autentication_form" novalidate="" ng-submit="submit_register()">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Email</span>
      <input type="text" name="email" ng-model="registerData.email" required="" />
      <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="autentication_form.email.$error" ng-if='autentication_form.email.$touched'>
        <span class="form-error" ng-message="required">You did not enter the email</span>
      </div>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="registerData.password" required />
      <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="autentication_form.password.$error" ng-if='autentication_form.password.$touched'>
        <span class="form-error" ng-message="required">Please enter the password</span>
      </div>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password confirmation</span>
      <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="registerData.password_confirmation" required="" confirm-pwd="registerData.password" />
      <div class="form-errors" ng-messages="autentication_form.password_confirmation.$error" ng-if='autentication_form.password_confirmation.$touched'>
        <span class="form-error" ng-message="required">Password confirmation required</span>
        <span class="form-error" ng-message="password">Password different</span>
      </div>
    </label>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: oops. just noticed David's solution.

Comment: Why not call $validate() instead of $setValidity? The logic is already in there.

Answer (score 4):

When developing, you can face the fact that you need to create your own checks, which will affect the validity of the form. If these checks are simple, such as a comparison of the two values, it is better to use a general guideline, than write your own checks for each situation. Look at [use-form-error](https://github.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error) directive.

Live example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/703qxbcg/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', ['use', 'ngMessages'])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope) {

  });
```

```css
.errors {
  color: maroon
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Stepan-Kasyanenko/use-form-error/master/src/use-form-error.js"></script>

<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">

    <form name="ExampleForm">
      <label>Password</label>
      <input ng-model="password" required />
      <br>
      <label>Confirm password</label>
      <input ng-model="confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" use-form-error="isNotSame" use-error-expression="password && confirmPassword && password!=confirmPassword" required />
      <div ng-show="ExampleForm.$error.isNotSame" class="errors">Passwords Do Not Match!</div>
      <div ng-messages="ExampleForm.confirmPassword.$error" class="errors">
        <div ng-message="isNotSame">
          Passwords Do Not Match (from ng-message)!
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I did (using `ng-pattern`):

```
<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>New Password</label>
  <input ng-model="user.password" name="password" type="password" required ng-pattern="'.{8,}'" />
  <div ng-messages="form.password.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Password required.</div>
    <div ng-message="pattern">Password must be at least 8 characters.</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
<md-input-container class="md-block">
  <label>Confirm Password</label>
  <input ng-model="user.confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" type="password" ng-pattern="user.password|escapeRegex" required />
  <div ng-messages="form.confirmPassword.$error">
    <div ng-message="required">Password confirmation required.</div>
    <div ng-message="pattern">Passwords do not match.</div>
  </div>
</md-input-container>
```

And the following filter converts the `ng-pattern` regex to a literal:

```
module.filter('escapeRegex', function(){
  return function(str){
    return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

ngMessage works by adding $error.*message_field_name* to the DOM field name in the form object (within the scope of course). So if your DOM form name is **autentication_form** and the DOM field name is **password_confirmation**, you need to set $scope.autentication_form.password_confirmation.$error.*nomatch* (or whatever ngMessage name you want) to true to display the "Doesn't match" error.

Markup:

```
<input type="password" name="password_confirmation" ng-model="registerData.password_confirmation" required />

<div ng-messages="autentication_form.password_confirmation.$error">
                <div ng-message="required">Please repeat your password.</div>
                <div ng-message="nomatch">Doesn't match.</div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Code, nothing special, just watching both passwords:

```
$scope.$watch("registerData.password + registerData.password_confirmation", function () {
            $scope.autentication_form.password_confirmation.$error.nomatch = $scope.registerData.password !== $scope.registerData.password_confirmation;
        });
```

Answer (score -2):

i did using only ionic(html) validations.

New Password
    
    
    
    New Password is required

```
<label class="item item-input inputRadius">
<span class="input-label">Confirm Password</span>
<input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="passwordUpdateInfo.confirmPassword" name="confirmPassword" required>
</label>
<div ng-show="passwordUpdateForm.$submitted || passwordUpdateForm.confirmPassword.$touched">
<div ng-show="passwordUpdateForm.confirmPassword.$error.required" class="errorMessage">Confirm Password is required</div>
</div>
<div ng-show="passwordUpdateInfo.confirmPassword.length > 0 && passwordUpdateInfo.confirmPassword != passwordUpdateInfo.newPassword">
    Password not match..(amar from india)
</div>
<button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-disabled="passwordUpdateInfo.confirmPassword.length > 0 && passwordUpdateInfo.confirmPassword != passwordUpdateInfo.newPassword">Update</button>
```